# How to keep scroll position on Angular Application on FIrefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox

I've been struggling with this problem for a long time and coudn't find an answer. My Application contains a dynamic-sized feed that can be re-accessed via history.back for example, and in this case It is interesting to ba back on the same scroll position where I left. Seems like Chrome and few other browsers do it automatic, but on Firefox it doesn't.

I could go around this problem by setting a small timeout and finding the scroll position that was saved before, but I would like to know why is it not working straight like on other browsers. Using AngularScroll is not an option, and as I read it is activated by default, otherwise chrome would not be able to scroll automatic.

Setting a static height on the container fixes the problem, but I need to catch it via a directive when the scope is done and add this attribute, which doesnt work as well.